# Running multiple threads in Asynctask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I'm getting info from an URL and sending that info to multiple URLs. I'm running it on a "for" in AsyncTask but the fact is it doesn't continue if other action doesn't return an error or success. So I wanted to do it in an AsyncTask-ception but sadly Android didn't let me to do.

So, I have two AsyncTask classes. That's the class I send to websites:

```
class SendTo extends AsyncTask <Object,Object,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... strings) {
        ....
    }
}
```

That's the task which I get from websites:

```
class GetFrom extends AsyncTask <Object,Object,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... strings) {
        ....
        String param = anotherMagicalFunctionThatGivesParamToSend(strings[1]);
        for(i = 1; i < websites.length; i++){
            new SendTo.execute(websites[i],param);
        }
    }
}
```

But sadly I'm getting these errors on AS:

> Method execute must be called from the main thread, currently inferred
>   thread is worker
>
> Non-static method 'execute(Params...)' cannot be referenced from a
>   static context

So do you have any ideas or solutions or ways to achieve this? Thanks for helping.

Comment: `SendTo.execute(params);`. You cannot execute or start an AsyncTask in that way. That it even compiles! You should make an instance of your class first like `new SendTo().execute();`.

Comment: It makes no sense to start AsyncTasks from the doInBackground of another AsyncTask. Non sense. You could do in onPostExecute though.

Comment: @greenapps Plenty of reasons to start a task in the background of another task.  FOr example, you download a resource that requires you to download additional resources.  You may choose to do these in additional AsyncTasks.  The problem is he tries to call an instance method on a class.

Comment: @greenapps Please don't question my grammar, and I've written an example code so it may be wrong, if I'm getting errors but not about "You missed 'new'.", it means I have a successful code, right? Also, I guess I can't run multiple AsyncTasks together, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out in some of the comments and in the exception you are seeing, you cannot start an `AsyncTask` from arbitrary thread context (e.g. the `doInBackground()` method of another `AsyncTask`.  Rather than start them right then, collect your `String` "parameters to send" into an array or `Set` and return that from your `doInBackground()` method.  Then, in your `onPostExecute()` method that return value will be provided as an argument.  Walk through each entry in the array or `Set` and fire a new `AsyncTask` to handle that transaction.

If you want them to run in parallel, use the alternate `executeOnExecutor` for `AsyncTask`, otherwise they will each run serially.

You could also use your own `ThreadPool` to accomplish something similar, which could reduce the heap thrash with creating numerous `AsyncTask` objects, since they are 1 time use.

Answer (score 0):

Your first error: `Method execute must be called from the main thread, currently inferred thread is worker` is because you're calling your second `AsyncTask` from `doInBackground()` of your first task. `doInBackground()` is a worker thread, you cannot execute another task from a background thread, it must be from a `UI` thread. An `AsyncTask` is for short operations, if you require a more complex operation then considering using a `Thread`.

Your second error: `Non-static method 'execute(Params...)' cannot be referenced from a static context` is because you're calling your `AsyncTask` as if it were static and not an instance. Your call for `new SendTo.execute(websites[i], param)` seems OK except for that fact that you cannot have 2 parameters, the parameter for `execute()` is passed in as an array

What I would suggest is instead of having 2 separate tasks for seemingly similar requests is to instead have 1 task, and add a flag that defines the type of operation you want to do. (SEND or FETCH) then in your `doInBackground()` check the flag and do the specified operation. It seems you're sending data and then attempting to retrieve a response, so when your SEND operation is complete, add a secondary flag that you now want to retrieve that data and in your `onPostExecute()` re-run your task for the other operation.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you want to start `AsyncTask` to do something in background in parallel.

To do this, do not use nested `AsyncTask` but one should rather use `ExecutorService`, submit task to such worker pool, collect results, return from async task.

Some details are in [ExecutorService](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) docs for Android

Comment: No, the problem is he called execute on the class in a static context not on an instance.  You can run multiple AsyncTasks in parallel quite easily with executeOnExecutor.